# Django, идентичные подкатегории

Tags: django, view, model

Проблема в следующем: есть три модели в mysite.models, Category - родительская, Brand - дочерняя, Card - соответственно еще ниже. Правильно ли я их связал для грамотного отображения, вот код

models.py.

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    name_cat = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='URL')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name_cat',)
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_cat

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cats', kwargs={'cat_slug': self.slug})

class Brand(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='URL')


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Бренд'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Бренды'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('brand', kwargs={'brand_slug': self.slug})

class Card(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    boots_model = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name='Модель бутс')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='URL')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Цена')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, verbose_name='Размер')
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name='цвет')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        verbose_name = 'Объявление'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Объявления'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.boots_model

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('card', kwargs={'card_slug': self.slug})



views.py
___________________________________________________________________________________________________
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Brand, Card

def index(request):
    brands = Brand.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    cards = Card.objects.all()

    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'brands': brands,
        'cards': cards
    }
    return render(request, 'mysite/index.html', context)

def show_categories(request, cat_slug):
    brands = Brand.objects.filter(category__slug=cat_slug)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    cards = Card.objects.filter(category__slug=cat_slug)

    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'brands': brands,
        'cards': cards
    }
    return render(request, 'mysite/cats.html', context)

def show_brands(request, brand_slug):
    brands = Brand.objects.filter(slug=brand_slug)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    current_brand = Brand.objects.get(slug=brand_slug)
    cards = Card.objects.filter(brand__slug=brand_slug)

    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'brands': brands,
        'cards': cards,
        'current_brand': current_brand
    }
    return render(request, 'mysite/brand.html', context)


def show_cards(request, card_slug):
    brands = Brand.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    cards = Card.objects.get(slug=card_slug)

    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'brands': brands,
        'cards': cards,
    }
    return render(request, 'mysite/card.html', context)


def about(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mysite/about.html', {'categories': categories})


urls.py
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
urls. from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('card/<slug:card_slug>/', views.show_cards, name='card'),
    path('cats/<slug:cat_slug>/', views.show_categories, name='cats'),
    path('brand/<slug:brand_slug>/', views.show_brands, name='brand'),
]
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при добавлении подкатегории BRAND в админке и выбора категории Бутсы, Шиповки, Обувь для зала, она дублируется как на картинке, что в дальнейшем ведет к неправильному отображению при фильтрации по Бренду и Категории на выводе. Да и потом я понимаю, когда добавлю авторизацию и личный кабинет пользователя при добавлении объявлений, юзер попросту будет путаться куда ему нажимать для выбора Бренда при добавлении карточки объявления.

![картинка[image: ]]

Как решить данный вопрос, перекраивать моделс? Либо во вьюхе я не правильно отображаю связи. Такое ощущение, из за нагромождения количества в модели Brand(models.Model), обработчик просто не понимает что к чему относится, HELP!!!! HTML в порядке, фильтры точно правильно отобразил

[image: Как должно быть]

Comment: у вас Brand связан с Category. А потом Card связан и с Brand  и с Category. Это явно не правильная запись модели думаю отсюда и появляются ошибки

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Благодарю за ответ! Каким правильным образом тогда необходимо связать модели? Убрать из Card FK по Categoty?

Comment: ну как вариант. Вообще не уверен что стоит связывать категорию с брендом. У разных категорий могут быть одлинаковые бренды по идее. Я бы убрал связь категорию с брендом.

Comment: или сделать бренд-категория menytomany и задавать программно, чтобы удобнее было искать бренды в категории

Comment: При создании ManyToMany получается, что Бренды в перспективе будут наполняться  одинаково под все Категории, при обработке шаблонов видится, что будет гемор по фильтрации. Либо просто не вижу как реализовать, если есть идеи буду благодарен. Пока что идея @Vadim.Sharoikin не вязать Бренд с Категорией - более проще и эффективней